# JavaScript repeat-Polyfill: Does these code structure make sense?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I've tried to understand the code of the String.prototype.repeat()-polyfill.

Complete code here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat

I ask myself if the following part is logical:

```
    // Tries to cast the parameter 'count' to a number.
    count = +count;

    // If the cast fails ('count' has become NaN) then
    // assign 0 to the parameter-variable.
    if (count != count) {
      count = 0;
    }

    // Does some more checks with the parameter ...
    if (count < 0) {
      throw new RangeError('repeat count must be non-negative');
    }
    if (count == Infinity) {
      throw new RangeError('repeat count must be less than infinity');
    }
    // End of checks ...

    // Rounds the parameter to next lower integer.
    count = Math.floor(count);

    // Checks if count is 0. In that case: Terminate 
    // the function / Return an empty string.
    if (str.length == 0 || count == 0) {
      return '';
    }
```

Why not terminating after the cast fails (at the top)?

Instead assigning 0, run checks, checking against 0. And if that state is true THEN terminating.

Makes no sense to me.

Is there anything which I haven't understood?

Comment: sets the count to a number, if that fails, set it to 0, if it's LESS than 0 throw a range error ... I see no issue at all ... 0 isn't a range error, it's a valid value

Comment: I guess the second check with 'count == 0' shall check if something like 0.49 has been assigned as a parameter. This would become 0 because of Math.floor(). But that still doesn't explain why the function isn't terminated after the first check ...  ?:|  Weird ...

Comment: yeah, I guess you could return '' instead of set count = 0 .. looking again, I see now exactly where you're coming from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this polyfill needs to implement the same behavior as in the specs. Spec say if value is less than zero you should throw error.

Also, casting to number at the start is fine, but can directly call this function with invalid number like so:

```
var string = 'abc';
string.repeat(-1); // throws range error
```